# Detection of hazards in CPU

Tags: cpu

I have one question about processor **using pipelining**.

Can the processor **with instruction pipelining** work **without** hazard detection?

Comment: Why unvote ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pipelined processor can avoid all hardware for hazard detection by never having hazards (possibly with assistance of compiler scheduling) or by handling detection of hazard violation in software.

For a simple scalar pipeline, structural hazards are relatively easy to avoid, one need only insure that no hardware is shared between stages. This implies single-cycle instructions or fully pipelined execution.

The MIPS R2000 did not have any structural hazards except possibly for multiplication and division (since one would wish to read the result before starting another multiplication or division, it is not clear one could consider the lack of pipelining of these operations to be a structural hazard to be detected by hardware) . If one considers selection of a forwarding path as not detecting the data hazard of delayed availability of a result in the register file, then the MIPS R2000 only had data hazard detection related to memory access, multiplication, and division. For the R2000, software was required to place a nop in a load delay slot, but hardware did detect and handle the cache miss data hazard.

If multiplication had been implemented with a latency of two cycles, it might have been reasonable to require a compiler to insert a nop (when a move from HI or LO would otherwise immediately follow a multiply or divide instruction or, if these instructions had used a general purpose register for the destination, when that GPR was used as a source) to manage this data hazard. For a microcontroller, not having caches would be possible. This would leave only memory-mapped I/O as a source of data hazards. Some on-chip peripherals in a microcontroller might be able to support very short fixed latency that could be handled with delay slots (and the number of delay slots might be different than for real memory accesses *if* the compiler/programmer could distinguish these two cases).

(Detecting the data hazard from a cache miss is rather natural since the processor must detect a cache miss anyway. *Handling* the hazard is more complex.)

It would also be possible for a processor to treat the latency of all operations as two cycles (like cache-hitting loads in the R2000). The compiler would then be responsible for inserting instructions (possibly nops) into delay slots for instructions. If the processor was a true barrel processor, cycling through threads like staves on a barrel, then single cycle apparent latency could be provided for operations taking as many cycles as there were "barrel staves"; an inactive thread effectively inserts nops into what would be delay slots.

With simple pipelines some structural hazards could be present and avoided by the compiler. For example, a processor might have two register banks with only a single read port in each; the compiler would have to completely avoid bank conflicts for two source instructions, possibly by inserting register copy instructions, making a value available in both banks.

Similarly, software could handle data hazards where the worst case latency is too great to simply use delay slots via a spin loop that polled for readiness. (Readiness state might be provided by hardware or detected by the value of a result *if* the result can be guaranteed not to have a particular value, an impossible result value can be inserted beforehand into the long latency operation destination register. Having hardware provide readiness state but not be equipped to use such state to detect hazards seems silly, but such would be possible.)

Coarse-grained multithreading is another way to handle longer latency. Software could tell the processor to switch threads when the worst case latency would be impractical to hide. If software guarantees that the repeat rate of such longer latency operations is sufficiently low, two threads could hide the latency that would otherwise introduce a data hazard. (I would consider it hazard detection if hardware switched threads whenever such operations were decoded even if software had to guarantee a sufficiently low repeat rate as well.)